# How append a json data in select box with optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a newbie in jquery. I want to display JSON data to my select box. My JSON Data is

```
{  
   "Color":[  
      {  
         "Id":"1",
         "Attrib_name":"Color",
         "Attrib_value":"Red"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"2",
         "Attrib_name":"Color",
         "Attrib_value":"Blue"
      }
   ],
   "Size":[  
      {  
         "Id":"3",
         "Attrib_name":"Size",
         "Attrib_value":"5.6"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"4",
         "Attrib_name":"Size",
         "Attrib_value":"5.1"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to create optgroup with option based on the above json. i.e

```
<optgroup label="color">
<option>Red</option>
<option>Blue</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="size">
<option>5.6</option>
<option>5.1</option>
</optgroup>
```

I am stuck on how to start. Please help me to get rid of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the result of this code and paste it as HTML

What it does is iterate over your json object and create the elements.

```js
var json = {  
   "Color":[  
      {  
         "Id":"1",
         "Attrib_name":"Color",
         "Attrib_value":"Red"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"2",
         "Attrib_name":"Color",
         "Attrib_value":"Blue"
      }
   ],
   "Size":[  
      {  
         "Id":"3",
         "Attrib_name":"Size",
         "Attrib_value":"5.6"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"4",
         "Attrib_name":"Size",
         "Attrib_value":"5.1"
      }
   ]
}
console.log(
  Object.keys(json).map(a=>`<optgroup label="${a}">${json[a].map(b=>`<option>${b.Attrib_value}</option>`).join``}</optgroup>`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example of how you can do this. You just have to build your HTML and use a jQuery function to add it in the html file. Check my [codepen](https://codepen.io/ulrichdohou/pen/xzdpNj?editors=1111). Code is also bellow

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>

<select id="mySelect"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = {  
"Color":[  
  {  
     "Id":"1",
     "Attrib_name":"Color",
     "Attrib_value":"Red"
  },
  {  
     "Id":"2",
     "Attrib_name":"Color",
     "Attrib_value":"Blue"
  }
],
"Size":[  
  {  
     "Id":"3",
     "Attrib_name":"Size",
     "Attrib_value":"5.6"
  },
  {  
     "Id":"4",
     "Attrib_name":"Size",
     "Attrib_value":"5.1"
  }
]
};
var html = "";
for(var option in data){
   html += `<optgroup label="`+ option  +`">`;
   data[option].forEach(function(item){
   html += `<option value="` + item["Attrib_value"] + `" >`+ 
   item["Attrib_value"] +`</option>`
   });
   html += `</optgroup>`;
}
console.log('html',html);
$('#mySelect').html(html);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `jQuery` allows a nice api to create `dom elements` so I would use the following approach but other answer will work:

```js
var data = {  
   "Color":[  
      {  
         "Id":"1",
         "Attrib_name":"Color",
         "Attrib_value":"Red"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"2",
         "Attrib_name":"Color",
         "Attrib_value":"Blue"
      }
   ],
   "Size":[  
      {  
         "Id":"3",
         "Attrib_name":"Size",
         "Attrib_value":"5.6"
      },
      {  
         "Id":"4",
         "Attrib_name":"Size",
         "Attrib_value":"5.1"
      }
   ]
};


var select = $('<select/>');

$.each(data, function(g, colors) {
  
  var group = $('<optgroup/>', {label:g});
  
  $.each(colors, function(i, color) {
    var option = $('<option/>', {
      value: color.Attrib_value,
      text: color.Attrib_value
    });
    
    select.append(group.append(option));
  });
  
});

$('#dropdown').append(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='dropdown'></div>
```